# What does a + mean at the end of the permissions from ls -l?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

What is the plus sign at the end of the permissions telling me?

```
ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 benson avahi-autoipd 4096 Jan 27 17:37 docs
```

Here's the context:

```
cat /etc/issue
\CentOS release 5.3 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Answer (score 205, accepted):

It means your file has extended permissions called ACLs.

You have to run `getfacl <file>` to see the full permissions.

See [Access Control Lists](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/ch-acls) for more details.

Comment: `ls -le` on Mac OS X. http://serverfault.com/a/303752/63749

Comment: Synology NAS (DSM6.2) also support `ls -le` to show syno-acl permission details

Answer (score 43):

via man page 'ls'

"If the file or directory has extended security information,
the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed
by a '+' character."

This generally means the file is encumbered with access
restrictions outside of the traditional Unix permissions -
likely Access Control List (ACL).

Comment: "encumbered with access restrictions" - does that mean that a file or directory without a + has less restrictions?

Comment: @squarecandy :  No, the + can remove restrictions (so add permissions).  For example, in the current Ubuntu default, when you plug in an external drive, it gets mounted in /media/{yourusername}/, but the permissions on /media/{yourusername} are drwxr-x---+ and the owner and group are both root, so you'd expect nobody besides root to be able to do anything with anything in there.  But the ACL says user:{yourusername}:r-x, so in fact you do have access (but none of the other users do).

Comment: FYI, strangely on Debian's `man ls` page (GNU coreutils 8.26) it doesn't mention that usage of `+`, but `info coreutils ls` does

Comment: What can it mean "not generally"? :) I do not have the acl package installed, can it be acl nonetheless or is there something else this could indicate?

Comment: The `ls` man page from `coreutils 8.30` in RHEL 8.3 **does not** contain the string "extended".

Answer (score 0):

From the `acl` package in Ubuntu :

```shell
$ man acl | grep -1 '+'
     •   For files that have a default ACL or an access ACL that contains more than the three required ACL entries, the ls(1) utility in the long form produced by ls -l
         displays a plus sign (+) after the permission string.

$
```